# Google OAuth2 - No refresh token / permission to access data while offline

Tags: oauth, refresh, token, google-oauth

According to the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

Requests with access_type=offline in the querystring should grant a permission to access data while the user is offline and result in google sending a refresh token when the user accepts. This is no longer happening as of a few days ago. Does anyone know what changed or if there is a better way to go about getting an access/refresh token?

Comment: This is still a problem for us, but in case it helps anyone else: apparently this can occur if the account you are trying to link has already granted the permissions (in which case you need to revoke the permissions on that google account before trying again).

In our case it is happening even with revoked permissions.

Comment: Just tagged this as google-oauth, hopefully somebody will read it now.